# How to temporarily override a named file descriptor in bash?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a quite unusual problem in one of my bash scripts. I want to do something (in fact I want to create/remve LVs, this is MWE) like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# ...
exec {flock}>/tmp/lock
# Do something with fd ${flock} e.g. 
flock -n ${flock} || exit 1

# ...

lvs ${flock}>&-

# ...
```

The problem is the `${flock}>&-`. Why do I want this? The LVM tools complain with a warning about any opened file descriptors except for stdin, stdout and stderr. So when I drop this small redirecting part, the script works but writes out a warning message.

Thus I wanted to redirect the fd `$flock` *only for the LVM command* to be closed. I do *not* want to close the file but only redirect for this single command invocation.

In my case `$flock` is set to 10 (first free fd greater or equal to 10, see `man bash`). However I do not get the corresponding fd remapped as sketched above. Instead the `10` is considered a parameter of the (`lvs`) command and the stdout should be redirected. Of course this is not what I intend.

If I hardcode `10>&-` this works but is very bad style. For now I switched to completely hardcode the fd in the whole file. Nevertheless I would like to know how it would be done correctly.

Comment: That `exec` line isn't ever going to work. Is this your actual code? What exactly is contained in your `$flock` variable?

Comment: @larsks `exec` with just a redirection opens `/tmp/lock` for writing in the shell itself, with the file descriptor automatically allocated by the shell and assigned to the variable `flock`.

Comment: But `exec {flock}` like that will just get you `{flock}: command not found...`.

Comment: @larsks with /bin/sh that's true. With bash, it does what chepner said. See paragraph two of [redirection section of bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't use the dollar

Your example code has:

```
lvs ${flock}>&-
```

The correct syntax is:

```
lvs {flock}>&-
```

From the [redirection section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) of the Bash manual:

> Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form {varname}. In this case, for each redirection operator except >&- and <&-, the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to {varname}. **If >&- or <&- is preceded by {varname}, the value of varname defines the file descriptor to close.** If {varname} is supplied, the redirection persists beyond the scope of the command, allowing the shell programmer to manage the file descriptor himself.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I thought this syntax was only possible with `exec` to permanently close the fd. Nice to see it working here too.